# Difference between RequestBody and MultipartBody of OkHttp3 library?

Tags: android, image-uploading, multipartform-data, retrofit2, okhttp

I am new to Android & Http and trying to create an Image Upload task using Retrofit2. I am using the example given [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).

In this example the author has explained why we should use RequestBody or MultipartBody. I am unable to understand the difference and how I should upload few tags(strings) with my image.

Could anyone help what author means by:

> The description is just a string value wrapped within a RequestBody instance. Secondly, there’s another @Part within the request: the actual file. We use the MultipartBody.Part class that allows us to send the actual file name besides the binary file data with the request.

Comment: `MultipartBody.Part` is a nested class and `MultipartBody` seems to be an extension of `RequestBody`, so what's the confusion?

Answer (score 3):

In simpler words **RequestBody** can be used for json/String request while **MultipartBody** can be used for file request (images,documents..)

Comment: but, according to what @cricket_007 said, RequestBody is abstract... so, how would you implement it for JSON/String requests?

Answer (score 2):

A `MultipartBody` IS-A (concrete implementation of)  `RequestBody`

```
public final class MultipartBody extends RequestBody
```

The primary difference is that a `List<Part> parts` is provided to the class compared to not having one in the `RequestBody`

`RequestBody` itself is abstract, which means you cannot create one directly. When you get one from a method, it's one of its descendants, such as `FormBody`

You can [compare source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3) for exact differences.

Comment: that was useful to know :)

Answer (score 1):

**RequestBody** : used while sending data to server in simple way.

**MultipartBody** : used while breaking up the data in a POST request into different discrete types and send to server.

Comment: For content-type: application/json we just send an model object which automatically gets converted to Json and sent via OkHttp. Does OkHttp internally always convert everything into RequestBody and then sends it?